# Combine two collections with a range Condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection "product" with documents like these :

```
{"_id" : 142347106,"name" : "product 1"}
{"_id" : 135377126,"name" : "product 2"}
```

I have an other collection "price" :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59310a6bad6e99863c2a6860"),
    "region" : 1111,
    "price" : 7.6,
    "id_start" : 174683814,
    "id_end" : 174686813,
    "qte" : 3000
}
```

The price of a prodct can be found with the _id of product which is between "id_start" and "id_end".
So if I want to have the price of all products I can do the following query :

```
db.getCollection("product").find({}).forEach( function(myProduct) {
     db.getCollection("price").findOne({$and: [ { "id_start":{$lt: parseInt(myProduct._id) } }, {"id_end":{$gt: parseInt(myProduct._id)}}]})
});
```

This is working but my problem is I have a lot of documents, and when I run the query it always end with a "errmsg" : "Cursor not found, cursor id: ...

So I would like to find an other way to query, by using the aggregation framework for example.

Do you have idea ?

I could combine the two collections in one to aggregate but I don't really like the way :-/

Thank you very much !

Comment: I suppose the real question here is essentially *"How commited are you to this structure?"*. I can see where this came from, and whilst a reasonable fit for an RDBMS, such a "conditional join" is not really great for something like MongoDB. The only way I can immediately think of to handle this with current aggregation framework operators does not seem very practical to me, though it "may" be possible.

Comment: The big problem is the "range". For instance between the `id_end` and `id_start` here, the numerical difference is 2999. Is their maybe some pattern to the assigned id values? Or are they simply assigned an incrementing integer? I would be a "little" bit more on the practical side if for instance the integer was always a divisor of 20 or 50 or similar.

Comment: I really don't understand why the problem is the range. If it was a fixed value, would it be easier ? Please give me an example of query with aggregate with a fixed value if you prefer